# How to get variable from gulpfile to front-end script?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Is there any way to pass a variable from gulpfile to front-end script?

I'm trying to issue a command line deployment, and have a variable change depending on if I run: "gulp build --development" or "gulp build --production".

The command would deploy a version of the front-end script to pull data from test url or pull from production url.

Note: I'm using gulp-connect as my server.

Answer (score 1):

The first idea how to do it.
Use *[yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)* package to take a flag from command line, next use *[gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if)* combined with *[gulp-replace](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace)* to proper inject server address to one of your configuration js file.